# Set provider for SQL (DbConfiguration)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had program to create database SQL with Entity Framework code-first.

I am add possibility create Sqlite database, but that required adding a provider.

```
public class Configuration : DbConfiguration, IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);

        var providerServices = (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices));

        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", providerServices);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", providerServices);

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(this);
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
        => new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
}
```

And now when I trying create SQL database, I get errors:

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any,
> should be discarded.

Error source:

> .Net SqlClient Data Provider

From what I'm reading `SetDefaultConnectionFactory(this);` changes default config. But I can't find a provider for SQL database anywhere.

```
using (var context = CreateContext())
{
    InitializeAndUpgradeDatabase(context);
}

public DeviceModelContext CreateContext()
{
    return new DeviceModelContext(connectionString);
}

public static void InitializeAndUpgradeDatabase(DbContext context)
{
    if (context.Database.Exists())
        return;

    try
    {
        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It throws an error in `context.Database.CreateIfNotExists()` after `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

Comment: _"problem with provider"_ - show the actual error. And show the code where you create a database.

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: @CodeCaster Error: A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. Error source: ".Net SqlClient Data Provider". There isnt more information. It was working before I added Configuration class to set provider for sqlite. Now even if I remove this class it dont work for sql.

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: @jdweng user id=myId;password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=false;server=myName;database=TestDatabase;connection timeout=4;MultipleActiveResultSets=True. But it was working and I didnt change it.

Comment: I looks like the  connection string is for a SQL Server and not SQLite (see : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/).  You also need to download the SQLite driver for Net if you have not already : https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.  Make sure you are using the version for the size of the project you are using (64,32) and the operating system.

Comment: @jdweng For sqlite I have a connection string: "Data Source = TestDatabase.db" and it work. The problem is that database creation for Sql does not work now. And it crashes an error that says nothing for Net SqlClient Data Provider. I think problem is in class Configuration, because the constructor of this class is called when creating the database. but even if I remove this class it dont work.

Comment: What databae created wit hSQLite and have an extension of db?

Comment: @jdweng https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst I use it to create databese for connection  sqlite. For sql connection it is Entity Framework 6.4.4. And this sqlite required a provider. From what I understand, the SetDefaultConnectionFactory () method in Configuration () changes the default setting. I'm not sure if there are any changes to the app.config file but for some reason it crashes an error for .Net SqlClient Data Provider.

Comment: The provided is automatically installed when you download SQLite with the link I provided.  Does the database you generated work with GITHUB project? Did you recompile (clean build) the GIHUB project before using?  Either the version of Net you used to generate the database is not the same version of you current project or the version of SQLite is different.

Comment: @jdweng I do not know if I understood you correctly, so it is enough to install the System.Data.SQLite library and my provider has changed so that creating a database for SQL does not work? Thanks for the help

Comment: It is not clear when and how you created the SQLite database.  Looking at the GITHUB project there are versions in the csproj and sln files.  So I suspect there are compatibility issues and that everything should be rebuilt using your current configuration.  I do not know what changed between the time the database was created and what you are currently using.

Comment: @jdweng At last it turns out that this error was caused by entry to context.Database.CreateIfNotExists () multiple times at runtime;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was it created allways Configuration instance, and allways set SqlLite provider.

My solution:

```
public class Configuration : DbConfiguration, IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public SqlTypeEnum sqlTypeEnum = SqlTypeEnum.Sql;

    public Configuration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(this);
    }
    public Configuration(SqlTypeEnum sqlTypeEnum)
    {
        this.sqlTypeEnum = sqlTypeEnum;
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);

        var providerServices = (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices));

        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", providerServices);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", providerServices);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(this);
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        if(sqlTypeEnum == SqlTypeEnum.Sql)
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        else
            return new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created this class to code-configure my providers - because i have no control over the app consuming my class library - but the code is never run. Do I need to manually instantiate an instance of `Configuration`? How is the code in this class called please? What am I missing?